# How many lowercase strings of 8 letters contain the letters x and y?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am having difficulty solving the above problem.

I understand that the number of strings which have ONLY an $x$ in it is $26^8 - 25^8$, and the same goes for $y$, but I cannot wrap my head around how to solve for $x$ and $y$.

The answer I came up with is ${8}\choose{2}$ $\times 26^6$, the $8\choose 2$ coming from placing $x$ and $y$ into any of the $8$ spots onto the strong, and the $26^6$ filling out the rest of the spots with any letters.

I cannot shake the feeling that this answer is incorrect, and I am looking for someone to help walk me through the problem so I can get a better understanding of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is indeed incorrect because it has overcounted scenarios where you have more than one $x$ and/or more than one $y$ occurring.  For example, letting the positions chosen in the first step be colored red, you would have considered $\color{red}{XY}xaaaaa$ to be a different outcome than $x\color{red}{YX}aaaaa$ despite them both having the same letters in the same order.

For a corrected approach, consider counting the opposite event:  We have no $X$'s **or** we have no $Y$'s.

Let $A$ be the set of 8 letter strings where we have no $X$'s.  Let $B$ be the set of 8 letter strings where we have no $Y$'s.  Let $\Omega$ be the set of 8 letter strings with no restrictions.

Remember that $|A\cup B| = |A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$ and remember that $|\Omega| - |A\cup B| = |A^c\cap B^c|$, the total you are really looking for.

Comment: Never thought of taking the complement, thanks for that. If I'm not mistaken, A and B would both be 25^8, and A intersect B would be 24^8, correct?

Comment: @Fluxify That is correct.

Comment: Alright, that all makes sense. Thank you for the help!